# Change swing GUI to Processing GUI

Tags: java, swing, processing

I am trying to run https://github.com/anfractuosity/LSD in Processing.
The GUI.java is incompatible because it uses swing's GUI.
How can I change it so that it calls Processing's GUI instead?
I've tried a few combos from
https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/12774/embedding-papplet-in-java-jframe
But I cant get it right.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class GUI extends JFrame {


    GUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        try {
            BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("piet.jpg"));
             Graphics2D g2d = myPicture.createGraphics();
            int x = myPicture.getWidth();
            int y = myPicture.getHeight();

            HashSet<Line> lines = new HashSet<Line>();


            double [] arr = myPicture.getData().getPixels(0,0,x,y,new double[x*y*3]);

            double [] arr2 = new double[x*y];

            System.out.println(arr.length);
            int c=0;
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-3; i+=3) {
                double B = arr[i];
                double G = arr[i+1];
                double R = arr[i+2];
                double level = R * 0.2126 + G * 0.7152 + B * 0.0722;
                arr2[c++] = level;
            }

            LSD lsd = new LSD();

            double [] out = lsd.lsd(arr2,x,y);

            for(int i = 0; i < lsd.n_out; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)

                lines.add(new Line(out[7 * i + 0], out[7 * i + 1],
                        out[7 * i + 2], out[7 * i + 3]));

            }

            for ( Line l : lines) {
                g2d.drawLine((int)l.x1,(int)l.y1,(int)l.x2,(int)l.y2);
            }

            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
            add(picLabel);


        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        setSize(800,800);
            setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        new GUI();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just change a couple things and have this code work in Processing. Swing and Processing are completely different.

You're going to have to take a step back and understand what your code does. Describe what it does, in English. Then take that English and implement code that accomplishes the same thing in Processing.

To get the ball rolling, here are a few differences:

- Processing uses a `PApplet` instead of `JFrame`.
- Processing uses a `PImage` instead of `BufferedImage`.
- Processing uses a `PVector` class instead of `Point`.
- Processing does not have components like `JLabel`.

But like I said, it's not as simple as just substituting a few keywords and having it work. You have to take **what the program does** and then do that in Processing.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Please try something, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. Even what you have above helps alot.

Comment: So if I add `import processing.core.PApplet;`  then  `public class GUI extends PApplet {` , what would change in `GUI() {
setDefaultCloseOperation(PApplet.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`  ?  Thats the part I dont get

Comment: @daddydean You don't translate code by changing it one line at a time. You translate code by starting over from scratch in your target language and working towards the goal that the first program accomplishes. Can you describe, in English, what the first program does? After you have that description, take it and start over in Processing using that description as a guide.

Comment: Well, I thought Id try. Basically what the code is supposed to do is to extract line segments from an image, so like a much simplified contour/edge detection.
The result look like this: http://iie.fing.edu.uy/~jirafa/lsd/technical-report-fig14.html

Comment: @daddydean Cool. Can you work through the code and understand what it's doing? Can you write down a list of steps that the code does (in English)? Avoid language-specific keywords: say "shows a window" instead of "shows a JFrame". When you have that list of steps written down, you'll be able to implement them in Processing. That's how code translation works.